# Can Sklearn Imputer distinguish real zero values from zeros in place for missing values?

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, imputation

I am using scipy sparse matrices, which fill missing values in with zeros. I want to impute these missing values with the mean of the respective columns, and planned to do this with the Imputer in Sklearn. My question, does the Imputer distinguish between real 0 values in the data from missing values filled in with 0? I know the numpy function getnnz can distinguish between these, but my hope is that the Sklearn Imputer will not overwrite legitimate zero values with column means.